# How is it that the second derivative of a function can be 0 at a maximum?

Tags: derivatives

How is it that a maximum of a function can have the second derivative as 0? I thought the gradient of the tangent to the curve changed from positive to negative at a maximum and is therefore decreasing.

Comment: The function might simply be "too flat" at the extremum. Consider e.g. $f(x) = -x^4$.

Comment: How can it be flat at the maximum? I thought there was only one point where the function reaches the maximum

Comment: Indeed: if $f(x)=-x^4$, then the maximum is attained at $0$ and only at $0$. However, $f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)=0$; that's why we say that $f$ is very flat near $0$.

Comment: It's not that it is actually flat, it is just flatter than, say, $f(x) = -x^2$. Intuitively, the second derivative test is comparing the function to a parabola, trying to tell if it looks alike. One can power this test up by [looking at more derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test), which amounts to comparing the function locally to higher degree polynomials.

Comment: I believe you. I just don't see how. The gradient has gone from positive to negative and is therefore decreasing ie the change in the gradient is negative, not 0.

Comment: You may think of it as the slope changing so slowly around $x = 0$ that the second derivative doesn't see it. The slope is changing, overall, but around that exact point it is very, very slowly changing.

Comment: You say you don't see how this can be. Jose gave an example where it happens - what's your problem with the example $f(x)=-x^4$?

Comment: I thought differentiation could detect any changes, no matter how small.

Comment: A classic counterexample to that notion is $f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2}, & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\ 0, & \text{if $x = 0$} \end{cases}$. This function has a minimum at $x = 0$, and the value of $f(x)$ definitely does change if you move away from $x = 0$. Nevertheless *every single derivative* of $f$ is $0$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: $y=-x^6$ at $x=0$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $g(x) = 4x^3.$

This is an increasing function. It is increasing everywhere you look.
No matter what values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ you choose,
it is always true that if $x_1 < x_2$ then $g(x_1) < g(x_2).$
Even if $x_1 = 0$ or $x_2 = 0.$

So in particular the function $g(x) = 4x^3$ is increasing at $x = 0.$

But the derivative of $g(x)$ is $g'(x) = 12x^2.$ Therefore $g'(0) = 0.$

This is why you cannot just look for "the derivative is zero" to tell you whether you have a local extremum at a given point. In this case we have an *inflection point*
in the graph of $y = g(x)$ at the point $(x,y) = (0,0).$

On the other hand, the function $h(x) = -4x^3$ is decreasing everywhere.
Its derivative is $h'(x) = -12x^2.$ Therefore $h'(0) = 0.$

This means that at $x = 0,$ both of the functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ have zero first derivatives, even though one function is increasing and one is decreasing.
If you only look at the first derivative of a function and find that it is zero, you can't tell whether the function is increasing or decreasing at that point.

Of course a positive first derivative implies and increasing function and negative implies decreasing. It's just the reverse implication that doesn't always work.

---

Now consider the function $f(x) = -x^4.$ This function clearly has a maximum at $x = 0,$
because $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) < 0$ whenever $x \neq 0.$

The derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(x) = -4x^3 = h(x).$
So we know the derivative is positive whenever $x < 0$ and is negative whenever $x > 0.$
That also tells us that a maximum of $f(x)$ occurs at $x = 0.$

But the second derivative of $f(x)$ is $f''(x) = h'(x) = -12x^2.$
So $f''(0) = 0.$

The second derivative of $f(x)$ is zero.

But that doesn't change the fact that the gradient of the curve $y = f(x)$
goes from positive to negative exactly as we pass $x = 0.$
The reason is because the value of $h(x)$ goes from positive to negative exactly at zero, despite the fact that the derivative of $h(x)$ is zero at $x=0.$